# how to show that a open set of $S^3$ is simply connected?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $B$ be the union of the compactification point and $(\mathbb R^3-X)$ in the one-point compactification of $\mathbb R^3$. (Here $X$ is a closed ball in $\mathbb R^3$.)

Then I think $B$ is somehow simply connected..but not able to prove it.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried thinking about the analogous problem for $\mathbb R^2$, in which case you can visualize the one point compactification of $\mathbb R^2$ as $S^2$?

Comment: Let $a$ be the centre of $X$. For any point $x$ in $B$ define $f(x)$ to be the point on the ray $ax$ such that $d(a,f(x)) = 1/d(a,x)$ (with the obvious definition for the compactification point). This is a homeomorphism of $B$ onto a simpler set.

Answer (score 1):

We may take $X$ to be $\{x\in\mathbb R^3:\|x\|\le 1\}$.

The mapping $f:X^\circ\to B$ given by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} x/\|x\|^2 & \text{if }\|x\|>0, \\[6pt]
\text{the compactification point} & \text{if }x=0,  \end{cases}
$$
is a homeomorphism from $X^\circ$ to $B$ (where $X^\circ$ is the interior of $X$).  Therefore if $X^\circ$ is simply connected, then so is $B$.

Answer (score 0):

The space is homeomorphic an open ball in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

I would look first at the analogous case : $X$ closed ball in $\mathbb{R^2}$ imbedded in the sphere $S^2$ by a stereographic projection from the North pole.